# RPM deletes files after post install script has been run not before it

Tags: linux, rpm, packaging, fpm

Problem: there's an RPM (created by FPM package generator) that is supposed to install a new version of our software.

In it, a couple of .sh files were removed from default installation compared to the old version of this rpm. Instead, they should be automatically created from "defaults" folder in post-install script.

The problem is: post install script first checks if the files are present so that it does't overwrite them, and it seems that they *are* because for some reason RPM installer only deletes these old files AFTER the post-install script gets executed. As a result these default files don't get created unless you repeat the rpm installation.

What can be done about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [this great page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Scriptlets?rd=Packaging:ScriptletSnippets) presenting the order in which the `rpm` scripts run (from both the old and new package)

You could consider moving your transactions to the `%posttrans` section instead of the `%post` section, then the files from the old package should have been removed.